# Test case with @Quarkus annotation throws error (using Intellij idea plugin also)

Tags: unit-testing, quarkus

junit test case not working with annotation @QuarkusTest.

get below exception:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.model.QuarkusModel io.quarkus.bootstrap.utils.BuildToolHelper.enableGradleAppModel(java.nio.file.Path, java.lang.String)

if I remove annotation @QuarkusTest
then it considers it otherwise doesnt even consider it in mvn clean test command too.